# Angularjs ng-model set value on load?

Tags: angularjs

I'm working with Angular js, and I created an input field with a list in typeahead :

```
<input type="materialid" ng-model="material"  
typeahead="material as material.ID for material in materials | 
filter:{ID:$viewValue} | limitTo:10"  
typeahead-editable="false" typeahead-min-length="0" />
```

My wish would be to automatically set a value (which is in the list) at page load.

For example, if the list of materials is `{hammer, handsaw, screwdriver, drill-bit...}`, I would like to automatically select "screwdriver" at load.

**EDIT :**

I was not enough specific.
Here is my html (a part of my table)

```
   <tbody ng-repeat="line in linesTest">
      <tr>
        <td>    
          <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="monid{{line.id}}" checked="{{line.checked}}">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="materialid" ng-model="material" ng-init="{{line.type}}"  typeahead="material as material.ID for material in materials | filter:{ID:$viewValue} | limitTo:10"  typeahead-editable="false" typeahead-min-length="0" /><br/>{{material.LABEL}}
        </td>
        <td>
           <input class="poids" type="emptyload" ng-model="line.tar" ng-model="emptyload"/>
        </td>
        <td>
           <input class="poids" type="load" ng-model="line.pesee"/>
        </td>
        <td>
           <input class="poids" type="load" ng-model="line.poids"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
```

and this is my js :

```
$http.get('http://192.168.1.3/pesoweb/webservice/rest/materials',{ cache: true }).
success(function(dataList) {
    $scope.materials = dataList;
});

var id = 0;

$scope.linesTest = [
{id:id++, checked: "checked", type: "screwdrivers", tar:"0125", pesee:"21000", poids:"24545"},
{id:id++, checked: "", type: "handsaw", tar:"52632", pesee:"4524", poids:"24545"},
{id:id++, checked: "", type: "ALPHA", tar:"548485", pesee:"68465", poids:"75421"},
{id:id++, checked: "checked", type: "hammer", tar:"7825", pesee:"23541", poids:"74"}
];

$scope.addEmptyRow = function() {
  $scope.linesTest.push({id:id++, checked: "checked", type: "", tar:"", pesee:"", poids:""});
};

$scope.removeRow = function(id) {
  $scope.linesTest.remove(id);
};
```

I would like to create one row in my table for each line in my array.
$scope.materials is a JSON array.

Do you understand better now ?

Answer (score 3):

You can do that in the `controller`:

```
$scope.material = 'screwdriver';
```

Comment: +1. For reference, one could also use `ng-init`, but it's recommended not to do so. The official documentation (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngInit) is very clear that initialization should be done in the controller.

Comment: Yes, but my input is in a ng-repeat. I add row by row in my <table></table> from this array : 
    $scope.linesTest = [
    {id:"1", checked: "checked", type: "screwdrivers"},
    {id:"2", checked: "", type: "handsaw"},
    {id:"3", checked: "", type: "screwdriver"},
    {id:"4", checked: "checked", type: "hammer"}
    ];

Comment: @psv If your input is inside ngRepeat than I suppose you should have pointed that out in your question.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
ng-init="material = 'screwdriver''"

<input type="materialid" ng-model="material" ng-init="material = 'screwdriver''"  
typeahead="material as material.ID for material in materials | 
filter:{ID:$viewValue} | limitTo:10"  
typeahead-editable="false" typeahead-min-length="0" />
```